# Measuring Image of a Set Using Jacobian Integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, transformation

> Assume $T:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is a differentiable mapping and $E$ be a measurable set. Show that
>   $m(T(E))=\int_E |det(DT(x))|dx$.

I am thinking I might use the following Theorem, but I don't know how

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\phi : U → \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bi-Lipschitz mapping. Let $f : φ(U) → R$ be measurable. Then
$\int_U (f\circ \varphi)|\det D\varphi| = \int_{\varphi(U)}f$.

Answer (score 1):

The measure of a set is the integral of constant function $1$ over that set (with respect to the measure). Using 
$$
\int_U (f\circ \varphi)|\det D\varphi| = \int_{\varphi(U)}f$$
with $f\equiv 1$ yields the result.